# Slow WebView Dismissal and Rendering Glitches on 'Back' Button Press

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-inappwebview

**[Flutter In App WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/5.7.2+3)** on the **Navigator.pop(context)** view is not disposing smoothly. How can I resolve this rendering issue?